# When using spring-boot-starter-data-redis, how to set the eviction policy? LFU or LRU etc?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis

When redis is used as a caching technology through spring boot (`<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>`), i see few properties like TTL can be set in the `application.properties` file.
ex:

```
spring.cache.cache-names=cache1,cache2
spring.cache.redis.time-to-live=600000
```

and few more snippets from - [Appendix A. Common application properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/common-application-properties.html)

```
spring.redis.database=0 # Database index used by the connection factory.
spring.redis.url= # Connection URL. Overrides host, port, and password. User is ignored. Example: redis://user:password@example.com:6379
spring.redis.host=localhost # Redis server host.
```

But I am not able to figure out how to set the cache eviction policy like - Least Frequently Used or Last Recently Used etc.
**How and where do I have to provide this config details ??**

Comment: did you figure out the answer yet? :D I kinda need that info too lol

Comment: @solujic, Look in to redis.conf. There probably is no way to set it from Java code.

Comment: It's possible, see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Redis [cache documentation](https://redis.io/topics/lru-cache#maxmemory-configuration-directive) states:

> It is possible to set the configuration directive using the redis.conf
> file, or later using the CONFIG SET command at runtime.

Redis [configuration documentation](https://redis.io/topics/config#configuring-redis-as-a-cache) states:

```
maxmemory 2mb
maxmemory-policy allkeys-lru
```

Combining the two, the command to change the eviction policy is:

```
CONFIG SET maxmemory-policy allkeys-lfu
```

Using Spring Data Redis:

If using non-reactive Redis connection:

```
RedisConnection conn = null;
try {
    conn = connectionFactory.getConnection();
    conn.setConfig("maxmemory-policy", "allkeys-lfu");
} finally {
    if (conn != null) {
        conn.close();
    }
}
```

If using reactive Redis connection:

```
ReactiveRedisConnection conn = connectionFactory.getReactiveConnection();
        conn
                .serverCommands()
                .setConfig("maxmemory-policy", "allkeys-lfu")
                .filter(status -> status.equals("OK"))
                .doFinally(unused -> conn.close())
                .block(Duration.ofSeconds(5L));
```